# Slim PHP Templates and passing parameters as strings within DOM attributes

Tags: php, dom, parameters, templating, slim

I'm trying to use the AddThis widget to share content, but want to include test scores as a dynamic string when sharing to twitter. I am using page partials for the templating.

```
<div addthis-toolbox class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style 
social-width" style="width: 150 px" addthis:url="http://www.ourclient.com/quiz/score" 
addthis:title="I took the IQ Quiz, I got {{totalPoints}} points!" ></a>
```

However, totalPoints is populating as {{totalPoints}} instead of passing as a variable. Any ideas on how I can convert it to a string easily? I'm using the Slim PHP framework.

Comment: How are you rendering the view in your Slim route?

Comment: Where would I find out, I'm working from someone else's code and using Slim for the first time. Would it be in Slim\View.php ? Or would it be somewhere in the controllers?